# jquery check and change div width when click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, width, jscrollpane

i have a few images inside a DIV, with a horizontal scroll bar (jscrollpane).

i am first getting the width of all images and assigning that width to the container, but i want to make a button that will change the height of the photos (400px/600px). when i click the button to change the height i also need to re-calculate the width of all images - and that's my problem.

what in my code is broken to calculate the width of images and assign it to div?

my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.minus-button').click(function() {
  //alert('clicked');
    $(".scroll-content-item img, .scroll-content-item, .jspContainer").css('height', 200);
    $('.scroll-content').each(function(){
      var wrapper = $(this);
      var wrapperWidth = 0;

      wrapper.find('.scroll-content-item img').each(function(){
         wrapperWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      });

      wrapper.css('width', wrapperWidth);
    });
 });
 });
```

any ideas? thank you!
the link: http://bit.ly/TJaqC6

Comment: Please indent this so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, the img don't have a scroll-content-item class, so this will select all img that have a parent with a class of scroll-content-item http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
wrapper.find('.scroll-content-item > img').each(function(){
         wrapperWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
```

Comment: still not getting the new width, get the same width from when the site is loading.

Comment: I think you are calculating the widths correctly, I think you need to inform js-scrollpane of a change in the width. It doesn't pick it up the change automatically. 
Looking at the examples, there is on that shows how to reinitialise it when the container changes its width: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples

Comment: mm you are right, found the one with ajax, but i dont really understand it, because i am not too good at it, but will give it a try. thank you!